# Dynamic Title Tag in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, title

I am trying to dynamically populate the title tag on a website.  I have the following code in my index.php page

```
<?php $title = 'myTitle'; include("header.php"); ?>
```

And the following on my header page

```
<title><?php if (isset($title)) {echo $title;}
else {echo "My Website";} ?></title>
```

But no matter what I do, I cannot get this code to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Nothing. Even when I set the $title I always get the default value.

Comment: Is there another `<title>` tag in your `<head>`?

Comment: No, just one <title> tag appears.

Comment: To see whether there are obscure bugs, change "My Website" to something else and see whether it appears in the browser. Oh, maybe it's just in the browser cache?

Comment: when i change the "My Website" to something else it appears

Comment: Do you have any value for `$title` in `header.php`?

Comment: only if the $title is not defined - <title><?php if (isset($title)) {echo $title;}
else {echo "My Website";} ?></title>

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Is it possible your title variable gets set after the header is included? Also, Do other PHP scripts work correctly on that site?

Comment: It seems you are running not exactly the same code as posted here.

Comment: at this point, all I am doing in including files like header, footer.

Comment: the only difference is the header.php is in a subfolder

Comment: @bluefeet - Ensure in your header.php, the print of title does not inside a function. This against the function scope variables. Or use global, static class variables ...

Comment: Try to echo something in the point where you set the title, and then again in the footer. Check the resulting source. Are both echos apparent? If so, in what order?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works (tested it - create a new folder, put your first line of code in a file called index.php and the second one in header.php, run it, check the title bar).

You should double check if those two files are in the same folder, and that you're including the right header.php *from* the right index.php. And ensure that $title is not being set back to `null` somewhere in your code.

Learn more about Variable Scope [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Edit: Examples of visible changes would be:

```
TEST1<?php $title = 'myTitle'; include("header.php"); ?>

<title>TEST2<?php if ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you including the header file before or after you set the title variable? If you're including it before, then of course it won't be set.

if you're doing something like this in your index.php:

```
<?php
     include('header.php');
     $title = "blah blah blah";
?>
```

then it won't work - you include the header file and output the title text before the $title variable is ever set.

Comment: I am setting it before, I include it.

Comment: Is something in the header file resetting $title to null?

Comment: this one is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

try to declare the variable before using it

```
$title = '123';
require 'includes/header.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this old school method ..

In your Header file (for e.g. header.php)

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>'; 
?>
<?php  
if($GLOBALS['title']) {
    $title = $GLOBALS['title'];
} else {
    $GLOBALS['title'] = "Welcome to My Website";        
}
if($GLOBALS['desc']) {  
    $desc = $GLOBALS['desc'];
} else {
    $desc = "This is a default description of my website";      
}
if($GLOBALS['keywords']) {
    $keywords = $GLOBALS['keywords'];   
} else {
    $keywords = "my, site, key, words";     
}
echo "\r\n";
echo "<title> ". $title ." | MyWebsite.com </title>";
echo "\r\n";
echo "<meta name=\"description\" content='". $GLOBALS['title']."'>";
echo "\r\n";
echo "<meta name=\"keywords\" content='".$GLOBALS['title']."'>";
echo "\r\n";
?>
```

In you PHP Page file do like this (for example about.php)

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['title'] = 'About MyWebsite -This is a Full SEO Title';
$GLOBALS['desc'] = 'This is a description';
$GLOBALS['keywords'] ='keyword, keywords, keys';

include("header.php");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your header is stored in a different file (could be outside the root directory) then all the above solutions will not work for you because `$title` is set before it is defined.

Here is my solution:
in your `header.php` file you need to set the `$title` to be global by: `global $title;` then echo it in your title so:

```
<?php global $title; ?>
<title><?php echo isset($title) ? $title : "{YOUR SITE NAME}"; ?></title>
```

Then in every page now you can define your title after you have included your header file so for example in your `index.php` file:

```
include_once("header.php");
$title = "Your title for better SEO"
```

This is tested and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use functions and its a good way to work on real time web sites.

Do simple:

create an index.php file and paste these lines:

```
<?php include("title.php");?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php index_Title(); ?></title>
<head>
</html>
```

-- Then

Create a title.php file and paste these lines:

```
<?php
function index_Title(){
$title = '.:: itsmeShubham ::.';
if (isset($title)){
    echo $title;
    }else{
        echo "My Website";
    };
}
?>
```

It will work perfectly as you want and we can also update any title by touching only one title.php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo basename(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])['basename'],".php");
?>
```

This works. Since I'm using PHP I don't check for other extensions; use `pathinfo['extension']` in case that's required.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using `define();` function.
In your `header.php` file add following line :

```
<title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
```

And on that page where you want to set dynamic title, Add following lines:
EX : my page name is `user-profile.php` where I want to set dynamic title
so I will add those lines that page.

```
<?php
    define('TITLE','User Profile'); //variable which is used in header.php
    include('header.php');
    include('dbConnection.php');
?>
```

So my `user-profile/.php` file will be having title: **User Profile**
As like this you can add title on any page on your site

Answer (score 0):

### Example Template.php

```html
<?php
if (!isset($rel)) {$rel = './';}
if (!isset($header)) {
  $header = true;
?><html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
  </head>
<body>

<?php } else { ?>

</body>
</html><?php } ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Pages Your Content

```html
<?php
  $rel = './'; // location of page relative to template.php
  $pageTitle = 'This is my page title!';
  include $rel . 'template.php';
?>

Page content here

<?php include $rel . 'template.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using your code in my project and it works properly

My code in header:

```
 <title>
  <?php 
   if (isset($title)) {echo $title;}
   else {echo "عنوانی پیدا نشد!";} 
  ?>
 </title>
```

and my code in index.php:

```
<?php
  $title = "سرنا صفحه اصلی";
  include("./include/header-menu.php");
?>
```