# php - dymanic title

Tags: php, layout, header, footer

How to set dynamic title ?
This is my header file where i want to set title dynamically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php $title ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
```

the file from where i want send title

```
<?php
include "layout/header.php"; 
include "layout/footer.php";
$title = "my title";
?>
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298270/dynamic-title-tag-in-php

Comment: Try `<?php echo $title ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the title before including the header file.

```
$title = "my title";
include "layout/header.php"; 
include "layout/footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Awesome. Please mark this as correct then
-Happy Coding

Comment: I did but my reputation is not enough to up vote answers and comments, it's says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."  once i reached 15+ reputation your answer will automatically up voted. :)